# Get list of emails has sync contact iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have searched and found that it's impossible to get email address from setting in `iOS` devices. That's what I think because it's user's privacy.

But I did downloaded an app on AppStore name: Simpler Contact.
And it does get list email.

This is the screenshot

[image]

So anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: you really didn't have to hide "gmail.com" xD

Comment: Do you have any solution :)